# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'BlogDetailProps'

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma

I'm trying to create a blog. Here i need to create a page from the database. But it tells me that the Id property does not exist, although it is detected.

Here's the error with the ID

```js
where: {
      id: params.id,
    }
```

Here is the whole file

````js
import prisma from '@/lib/db';
import { FC } from 'react'

interface BlogDetailProps {
  params: {
    id: string,
  }
}

const BlogDetail: FC<BlogDetailProps> = async( params ) => {

  const post = await prisma.post.findFirst({
    where: {
      id: params.id,
    },
    include: {
      author: true,
    },
  });

  return (
    <div className='max-w-4xl mx-auto py-8'>
        <img src={post?.image} alt={post?.title} />
        <h2>{post?.title}</h2>
        <p>Written by: {post?.author?.name}</p>
        <div className='mt-4'>{post?.content}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default BlogDetail```
````

Comment: `interface BlogDetailProps { id: string; }` ?

Comment: it's the argument to your function component that you've got wrong: you need to destructure: `async({ params }) => {`

Comment: or you could do as @James says, if you don't expect anything other than `params` in the props object, in which case you can simplify it to have the `id` and anything else you need as a direct prop